# Tuning MariaDB 10.2.9 innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

Based on [this](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/poorly-tuned-databases-exact-heavy-toll-3-mariadb-tuning-tips) blog post, I'm looking for correct value to be set for `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size`, `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

We have dedicated VPS Centos 7 with:

- 4x CPUs
- 16GB RAM
- 30 GB SSD disk space

Not to mention that there are other services running along (Nginx, PHP7-FPM, Redis, Elasticsearch).

What values should I use for best performance? What about increasing other variables (`innodb_log_file_size`, `query_cache_size` etc.)?

Comment: For "best performance," your database should not have to share its server with any other services.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot well, there are pros&cons having a database on a separate (remote) server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sharing with a bunch of other things, let's assume only 8GB *available* to MySQL.  Then

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = OFF
```

You don't need to change the log_file (`innodb_log_file_size`, etc) unless you find that MySQL is really busy.

For now, other settings can be left at defaults.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory